# Lie Algebras of compact lie groups

Tags: soft-question, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Can we know that a lie group is compact by studying its lie algebra ? If we consider the exponential function from the lie algebra to the corresponding lie group , we expect that exponentiating linear combinations of the generators in which the coefficients are extremely large gives rise to group elements extremely far away from the identity. So , how can exponentiating vectors whose norm is extremely large gives rise to group elements near the identity ?

Comment: I guess that the exponential of a matrix ( the generator ) can be near to the identity because matrix multiplications is not very simple so we can have $e^{tX}$ near one even if $t$ is very large. So for compact lie groups we have to use special $X$. Is this right ?

Comment: It seems that one can rotate the generators in the lie algebra into each other. Then can we expect that some metric on the lie algebra contains information about the compactness in its eigenvalues , say.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that the Lie algebra ${\mathfrak g}$ of your (connected!) Lie group $G$ has zero center ${\mathfrak g}_0$. Then the necessary and sufficient condition for  $G$  to be compact is that the Killing form of   ${\mathfrak g}$ is negative definite. This result will be in any textbook on Lie theory. Start [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_Lie_algebra). If the center ${\mathfrak g}_0$ is nonzero, you cannot conclude anything and need further information about the fundamental group of your Lie group.

Comment: Maybe in the case with center you first want to say that a necessary condition is that the quotient by the center has negative definite Killing form (or equivalently that the Killing form is negative definite modulo the center). Then indeed compactness is equivalent to asking that the analytic subgroup generated by the center is compact.

Comment: @YCor: Yes, indeed, or one can require the rank of $\pi_1(G)$ to be equal to the dimension of ${\mathfrak g}_0$. In any case, it all depends on what kind of information about $G$ is available (besides the Lie algebra).

Comment: Yes. The main part of my comment was the previous one. In particular, a (fd real) Lie algebra is Lie algebra of a compact group iff the Killing form is negative definite modulo the center.